# How to start the Synergy client from the command line?

Tags: windows, synergy

Starting the dialog box is easy enough. In my case:

```
C:\Program Files\Synergy\synergy.exe
```

But then I have to click on *Start*.

Is there a flag I can add that would start the client and skip the dialog box? Can't seem to find any docs on this.

Answer (score 4):

You can start Synergy from the command line based on your existing settings, but it takes a bit of fiddling with the config GUI.

First, we'll need to get the command line string from the GUI, like so...

1. Open Synergy
2. Click the File menu (Windows/Linux) or the Synergy menu (Mac)
3. Click the Preferences menu item
4. Change Logging level to Debug
5. Click OK
6. Click Apply
7. Click Stop
8. Scroll up in the log until you see "INFO: command:"
9. Copy the text after "INFO: command:"
10. Change the Logging level back to Info

You should have a command line that looks something like this (e.g. on a client)...

`C:\Program Files\Synergy\synergyc.exe -f --no-tray --debug DEBUG --name woody 192.168.1.1 :24800`

Now, open Command Line (Windows) or Terminal app (Mac/Linux) and paste in the log line and hit the enter key to start. To stop, use the Ctrl+C keystroke.

Source: [Run From Command Line](https://github.com/symless/synergy/wiki/Command-line)

Comment: Note on windows, this does not work in powershell, only in cmd.

Answer (score 3):

The server's executable is named `synergys`. Likewise, the client is named `synergyc`. Both have various command line options. The client has a mandatory argument: The server host.

Answer (score 1):

Been a while since I used Synergy as I switched to [Synergy+](http://code.google.com/p/synergy-plus/) a year or two ago. When I run Synergy+ it has an Options section and in that Options section is a "AutoStart..." button. Do you have something similar with Synergy?

Oh, actually I just found the [synergy docs](http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/) section ("autostarting") that you're after:

> Start synergy and click the
>   Configure... button by the text
>   Automatic Startup. The Auto Start
>   dialog will pop up. If an error occurs
>   then correct the problem and click
>   Configure again.
>
> On the Auto Start dialog you'll
>   configure synergy to start or not
>   start automatically when the computer
>   starts or when you log in. You need
>   Administrator access rights to start
>   synergy automatically when the
>   computer starts. The dialog will let
>   you know if you have sufficient
>   permission.

Comment: Hi Chris thanks for your answer.

Well, I've got autostart enabled at the moment. The thing is, I want to turn "autostart off" as this is on a laptop and It is annoying to have synergy try to connect to the server when mobile (on train for example). So I want to be able to start synergy off the command line while at the same time skipping the dialogue box.

I'll take a look at synergy+ now.

Answer (score 1):

If you first install [Synergy as a service](http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/autostart.html), you could start and stop the *service* from the command line:

```
net start "Synergy Client"
```

to start, or

```
net stop "Synergy Client"
```

to stop Synergy.

For other options, see [this Microsoft Technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc736564%28v=ws.10%29.aspx#BKMK_cmd).

Comment: On windows, the service has been renamed to "Synergy"